Please help identify 8- pin chip
I have been tasked with reverse-engineering a low-voltage boost converter.  We have mostly finished the schematic except for one particular chip.
I am hoping that some kind soul can help identify this chip.

It's an LM3488MM from Texas Instruments. A switching regulator MOSFET controller in an MSOP8 package.

From the datasheet the marking is S21B. Just to be confusing on this and similar TI packaged parts the second line is the part identification. You can find the MGAF on other parts like the LM5007s which this isn't.


Image Source
